# How can I tap into onUserDelete?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm currently building a plugin that uses a table that contains rows with an 'active' field set to 1.

If an admin deletes a user from the system, I want to change this value to 0.

I found an 'onUserDelete' event documented but can't work out where or how to use it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT UPDATED:

I now have this code in the init() function of my plugin controller but deleting a user does not seem to fire the code:

```
    parent::init();

    craft()->on('users.onDeleteUser', function(Event $event) {
        $user = $event->params['user'];

        $userId = $user->id; // ???????

        $craft->memberships_membership->cancelMembershipById($userId);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#events) on events, they follow this pattern:

```
craft()->on('component.eventName', function(Event $event) {
    // ...
});
```

So in your example, it'd be something like this and you'd want to add it to your plugin's `init()` method in the main plugin class.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    craft()->on('users.onDeleteUser', function(Event $event) {
        $user = $event->params['user'];
        $userToTransferContentTo = $event->params['transferContentTo']
    });
}
```

The full list of available events and the parameters they have can be found [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference).

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't seem to work though. I've edited the question to show how my code looks at the moment.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that really helps. I feel like I'm close now. I can't seem to find how to get the user's id from that $user var which I believe to be of UserModel type? I've updated my question with the latest code.

Comment: You're correct and that should do it!

Comment: It doesn't :( I'm pretty sure it's not firing. The same code to cancel a membership is used elsewhere so I know that works. I'm not sure `$userId = $user->id;` is correct because I can't see an `id` mentioned in the UserModel documentation.

Comment: I WORKED IT OUT! I'd stupidly misinterpreted what 'main plugin class' meant. Thanks for all of your help on this :)